# android VideoView animation not performed smoothly

Tags: android, animation, android-videoview

I have a VideoView as simple as this:

```
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/video"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

in this view a play a live streamed video. The VideoView is nested in a LinearLayout which is animated from time to time (moves from behind the screen and puts the VideoView on the 1st plan of the screen). The animation works fine and the VideoView is being animated. The problem is that that the VideoView is not animated smoothly, meaning there's a lag before the VideoView "catches up" the rest of the LinearLayout which is animated. That results in an effect that the VideoView displays at the beginning and is simply put at the final place.

I wonder if there's a way to improve the performance to have a real animation of the VideoView.

I suppose that it's a heavy UI component but at the same time I hope it could be still improved on my side...